# Where can I find professor Rafe Mazzeo's note Analysis and Geometry on Asymptotically Hyperbolic Spaces?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm looking for *Analysis and geometry on asymptotically hyperbolic
spaces* by *Rafe Mazzeo*. This is a lecture he gave at ETH summer 2003. This is a reference listed in *Pierre Albin*'s lecture note *Analysis on Non-Compact Manifolds*, but I can't find it from Google search. Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you just email Mazzeo and ask him for a copy? He is at Stanford and is a very friendly guy.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan : Given how disorganized mathematicians are, my guess is that “user2856673” is in fact Mazzeo hoping that somebody can send him a copy of his own misplaced notes. =)

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Michael: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here, but it sounds disrespectful to mathematicians. No I'm not Mazzeo. I'm a theoretical physicist looking for reference on these topics.

Comment: @Michael Since your first conjecture turned out to be wrong, your next one should be that I am Mazzeo. (I am not.)

Comment: @user2856673 : I did not expect that reaction.  I suppose theoretical physicists are very organized? Anyway, this is certainly something I would do, and have done, ("Does anyone happen to have a copy of the notes I gave you last week?") Perhaps nobody can relate to me.  There are jokes about coffee and mathematicians,  and jokes about absent minded professors, perhaps the latter is a protected characteristic now.

Comment: I have known Mazzeo since his undergraduate days. He is *not* that disorganized. :) And I already alerted him to this post, so go ahead and email him at Stanford. I'm sure he'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin : well, I don’t know him at all, but I indeed am that absent minded. I thought my comment would be funny...I can delete it if it is deemed out-of-line.